# how to fix "Unable to initialize device PRN" in Lua? (While using Vs Code)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, lua

> Executing task in folder All Codes: lua54 "C:\Users\Harsh\Documents\Codeing and Art\Lua\All Codes\Test.lua" <

Unable to initialize device PRN

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Now i have a path set in my c drive named lua and when i use cmd it workes fine but in vs code it doesnt work fine for some reason

Comment: What's inside `Test.lua` ?

Comment: Just a simple print command